# Conditional TypoScript constants in root template

Tags: typo3, typoscript, facebook-opengraph

I use [`jh_opengraphprotocol`](http://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/jh_opengraphprotocol) on a site with two languages. The documentation tells me to set up the constants in the page root template as such:

```
plugin.jh_opengraphprotocol.description = Foo Bar
plugin.jh_opengraphprotocol.sitename = Foo Bar
plugin.jh_opengraphprotocol.image = /uploads/tx_jhopengraphprotocol/foobar.jpg
plugin.jh_opengraphprotocol.type = website
plugin.jh_opengraphprotocol.title =
```

This works, and the OG tags are shown in the frontend. But my website is bilingual – so where could I add a condition for the language here? I tried this:

```
[globalVar = GP:L=0]
plugin.jh_opengraphprotocol.description = Foo Bar German
plugin.jh_opengraphprotocol.sitename = Foo Bar
plugin.jh_opengraphprotocol.image = /uploads/tx_jhopengraphprotocol/foobar.jpg
plugin.jh_opengraphprotocol.type = website
plugin.jh_opengraphprotocol.title = 
[end]

[globalVar = GP:L=1]
plugin.jh_opengraphprotocol.description = Foo Bar English
plugin.jh_opengraphprotocol.sitename = Foo Bar
plugin.jh_opengraphprotocol.image = /uploads/tx_jhopengraphprotocol/foobar.jpg
plugin.jh_opengraphprotocol.type = website
plugin.jh_opengraphprotocol.title = 
[end]
```

But then the constants are not set *at all*. How do I have to set them for both languages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the default language no condition is needed. Only make the changes for the alternative language:

```
plugin.jh_opengraphprotocol.description = Foo Bar German
plugin.jh_opengraphprotocol.sitename = Foo Bar
plugin.jh_opengraphprotocol.image = /uploads/tx_jhopengraphprotocol/foobar.jpg
plugin.jh_opengraphprotocol.type = website
plugin.jh_opengraphprotocol.title = 

[globalVar = GP:L=1]
plugin.jh_opengraphprotocol.description = Foo Bar English
[end]
```

Comment: 3 years later ... how to work with the constants in language so that they can be edited in the web -> Template -> constant-editor